# Execute a bash command string verbatim (including expansion and escaping)

Tags: bash, scala, process

I am looking for how to submit a string to external bash verbatim. Bash should handle wildcard expansion and escaping.

The testing is with the process library:

```
import sys.process._
```

That  imports the required process DSL implicits into scope.

Let us try an **escaping** test: here is the desired result run on the bash shell:

```
$echo -ne 'abc\t\n' | tr '\t' 'T'
abcT
$
```

Let us try in the sys.process:

```
scala> "echo -ne 'abc\t\n' | tr '\t' 'T'" !!
warning: there were 1 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
res16: String =
"-ne 'abc ' | tr ' ' 'T'
"
```

*Fail* ..pretty different than on command line..

Now let us try an **expansion** test (OS/X flavor):

```
scala> "open /shared/adm*" !!
warning: there were 1 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
The file /shared/adm* does not exist.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit value: 1
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.slurp(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:131)
    at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.$bang$bang(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:101)
```

*Fail*.. Here the wildcard expansion was not performed.

So .. should I resort to the old java Process way - which is to execute "bash -c" and then send in the entire command line?

Comment: You are asking for features that bash implements like pipes and wild cards so run them through bash! See http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder for some enlightenment.

Comment: @DavidWeber  That page does not address either expansion or escaping- and I was already aware of pipes and wildcards support as described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: There is a difference between running an external command (`sed`, `cat`, `ls`, etc.) and commands that are build in `bash` such as `cd`, `|`, and wildcards. Using the `process` package does not allow you to run `bash` commands from strings.

Here is my attempt to implement what you want in Scala (2.10). The first approach only uses methods provided by the `process` package. The second approach is indirectly invoking `bash` to run the entire command.

```
import sys.process._

val f = (Seq("echo", "-n", "abc\t\n") #| "tr '\\t' 'T'").!!.trim
println(f)

val g = Seq("/bin/sh", "-c", "echo 'abc\t\n' | tr '\t' 'T'").!!.trim
println(g)
```

Comment: i was hoping to avoid complicating the call to process: the above will work but then loses the convenience of just "create a command string and fire away"

Comment: I agree it might not be as short as running it directly from bash, but I feel it is much shorter and less verbose than using Java Process.